# How do I add a simple query string jQuery script to WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add the ability to populate fields dynamically via query strings in WordPress.  I've created `dm_email.js` containing the following:

```js
    jQuery(function( $ ){
    
    //grab the entire query string
    var query = document.location.search.replace('?', '');
    
    //extract each field/value pair
    query = query.split('&');
    
    //run through each pair
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
    
    //split up the field/value pair into an array
      var field = query[i].split("=");
      
    //target the field and assign its value
      $("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']").val(field[1]);
    
    } 
    });
```

and placed this in `mytheme/js/dm_email.js`

In my `functions.php` I've add the following:

```js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dm_query_string' );
    function dm_query_string() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'dm_query',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dm_email.js', 
        array('jquery') 
    );
    }
```

But the expected functionality keeps failing.  If I add the following to `wp_head()` I get the expected functionality but of course I also get a lot of issues with other scripts/plugins:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    
    //grab the entire query string
    var query = document.location.search.replace('?', '');
    
    //extract each field/value pair
    query = query.split('&');
    
    //run through each pair
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
    
      //split up the field/value pair into an array
      var field = query[i].split("=");
      
      //target the field and assign its value
      $("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']").val(field[1]);
    
    }
  });
</script>
```

I'm at a loss as to where I've gone wrong with either the `js` or `functions.php` any help or guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your script into footer and not to head. You can do the followig:

First be sure you enqueued **jQuery**.

Changes in functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'dm_query',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dm_email.js', 
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0.0',
    true
);
```

Changes in Your js:

```
(function($){ /* Your Code */ })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

add This code in **function.php** File.

```
function AddJs(){

      wp_register_script('dm_query',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dm_email.js');
      wp_enqueue_script('dm_query',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dm_email.js');
}
add_action( 'init', 'AddJs' );
```

Note:in dm_email.js file replace **$** to **jQuery**. 
$ is get some time error in wordpress.